# Extra Square Brackets Being Added in array to JSON ouput

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have found that when converting my arrays to `JSON`, there are extra square brackets that are preventing the data from being parsed.

I make an `AJAX` call which prepares the data server side. The `C#` processes the data and turns it into an array of arrays for Google Charts to process.

It is all dynamic, so I have no idea how many arrays there will be, hence I cannot hardcode the arrays and I cannot loop the client side as the performance is shocking.

I don't think the `JSON` parser in the `JavaScript` is the issue, it is in the `C#` I have written.

I have added two `JSON` links, one is the output, the other is the expected output.

My C# is:

```
public List<object[]> CreateJsonMultiChartData(string serial, string guid, string datefrom, string dateto)
        {
            var serials = _context.RawData.Where(x => x.ProjectGuid == guid).Select(x => x.SerialNumber).Distinct().ToList();
            var projectUid = guid;
            var from = datefrom;
            var to = dateto;

            //Method to return data
            var g = new GetChartDataSprocs(_context, _configuration);

            List<object> chartData = new List<object>();
            var arrays = new List<object[]>();

            foreach (var s in serials)
            {
                var data = g.GetChartDataFromSqlServer(s, projectUid, from, to);               

                foreach (var item in data)
                {
                    var year = Convert.ToDateTime(item.ReadingDate).Year;
                    var month = Convert.ToDateTime(item.ReadingDate).Month;
                    var day = Convert.ToDateTime(item.ReadingDate).Day;
                    var hour = Convert.ToDateTime(item.ReadingDate).Hour;
                    var minute = Convert.ToDateTime(item.ReadingDate).Minute;
                    var second = Convert.ToDateTime(item.ReadingDate).Second;

                    var date = "new Date(" + year + "," + month + "," + day + "," + hour + "," + minute + "," + second + ")";

                    chartData.Add(
                        new ChartTestModel
                        {                            
                            ReadingDate = date,
                            ReadingValue = item.ReadingValue
                        });                    
                };

                arrays.Add(new[] { chartData });
            }

            return arrays;           
        }
```

My AJAX response is:

```
 public JsonResult GetMultiChartData(string serial, string uid, string from, string to)
        {
            var dateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(from).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            var dateTo = Convert.ToDateTime(to).AddMinutes(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            var g = new GetChartData(_context, _configuration);
            var items = g.CreateJsonMultiChartData(serial, uid, dateFrom, dateTo);
            //var dsItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(items);

           // return items;
            return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items, Formatting.Indented));
        }
```

My AJAX call is:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'ProjectCharts/GetMultiChartData',
        datatype: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        async: false,
        data: { section: section, uid: uid, from: from, to: to },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (d) {
            parsedData = $.parseJSON(d);               
            var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                { label: 'Date', id: 'ReadingDate', type: 'date' }, // Use object notation to explicitly specify the data type.
                { label: 'Data', id: 'ReadingValue', type: 'number' }, [parsedData]]);              
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
            var options = multiLineChartOptions();
            chart.draw(data, options);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
```

The output is at:

[Current JSON Ouput](https://jsonformatter.org/232f62)

The expected output is:
[Expected JSON Output](https://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator/cbff69fb)

Comment: On this line   `{ label: 'Data', id: 'ReadingValue', type: 'number' }, [parsedData]])`, was it intended to be `[parsedData]`, what if you left it as `parsedData`?

Comment: I get the error `Uncaught Error: First row is not an array.`

Comment: The idea is that the chart API will process the arrays. I havent worked out how to use the `parsedData` properly yet, I am hoping this will fix part of the problem.

Comment: Notice that on line: `arrays.Add(new[] { chartData });` you  add to `arrays` a new array that has items of type List<object>. Thats three nested list\array types. Why not add the List<object> directly? 
(aka: `arrays.Add(chartData)` - assuming you also change the initialization to `arrays = new List<List<object>>();`)
I think this might be causing the extra "array layer" in your serialized JSON.

Comment: @JonyVol That removed the extra bracket, not I get an error in the browser console `Uncaught Error: Row 0 has 1 columns, but must have 2`

Comment: It is the `arrayToDataTable`. It is only seeing one column in the part where I add the `parsedData` array of arrays. I am not sure how to tell it how to view each column in each array without looping client side.